# combining loops and some dplyr functions

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, conditional-statements, counting

I'm working on a large dataset where I'm trying to calculate the number of TI's for
which the frequency of words stored in the column named "word" is greater than 0.
I managed to calculate this using the dplyr package (there might be easier ways of
doing this but I'm unfortunately not a very efficient coder).
I would like to repeat this exercise for a select list of words using a loop.
Let's say I want to repeat my exercise (shown below) for all the words stored in the following vector

`keywords <- c("contagion", "crisis", "risk")`

I don't really have much experience at all working with loops.
If someone can help me with this, I would be saving an incredible amount of time!

```
df <- data.frame(TI=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                 word=c("contagion", "contagion", "crisis", "risk", "money"),
                 frequency=c(2, 2, 1, 3, 4))

count <- df %>% 
        filter(word=="contagion" & frequency>0) %>%
        group_by(TI) %>% 
        tally() %>% 
        nrow()
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the 'keywords', then `filter` where the 'word' is that keyword, and frequency is greater than 0, then grouped by 'TI', get the `tally` and the number of rows

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(keywords, ~ df %>%
                  filter(word == .x, frequency > 0) %>%
                  group_by(TI) %>%
                  tally() %>% 
                  nrow())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps!

Comment: thank you! unfortunately, I could not vote on the answer as I do not have enough "reputation" on StackOverflow (I'm new to the platform). But I do really appreciate the help.